# Using RegEx to pull data from between pseudotags (can't use BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, xml, regex, import, html-parsing

I've been trying every which way and no matter what I do I get a blank output. Here's a shortened version of what I have in my file that I'm trying to import and parse:

```
<PRESOL>
<DATE>0310
<AGENCY>Defense Logistics Agency
<DESC>*(this is full of HTML tags and the such)*
<URL>https://www.fbo.gov/spg/DLA/J3/DSCR-BSM/SPE4A713R0575/listing.html
<SETASIDE>N/A
</PRESOL>
```

I'd like to create a table with a column for each DATE, AGENCY, DESC, URL, and SETASIDE, as there are 100s of entries just like this between the "PRESOL" tags. There are also returns after each of the tags' data, which comes up as "\n" when I pull it in to python. Here's the RegEx I tried so far (s is the variable I read the file in to and re has been imported):

```
testall = re.findall(r'<PRESOL>\n<DATE>(.*?)\n<AGENCY>(.*?)\n<DESC>(.*?)\n<URL>(.*?)\n<SETASIDE>(.*?)\n</PRESOL>', s)
```

I tried this without the "\n"'s as well as with (.+?) instead of (.*?).

Let me know if you need any more information in order to help me, and any help is greatly appreciated. My end game is to easily be able to import data from ftp://ftp.fbo.gov/FBOFeed20130311 (there seems to be multiple table types, but I'm focusing on PRESOL at the moment just to get this proof of concept off the ground.

Comment: When I output testall it gives me []

Comment: This doesn't seem to bear any relationship to XML (it seems to be a markup language of your own invention). Why have you tagged it XML?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was some sort of XML that I just wasn't understanding.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing... did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time and was able to build a parser function for the FBO data. Doubt you still need it but maybe this will help someone else.

```
def fbo_parser(fbo):
     split_fbo = fbo.split('<PRESOL>')
     n_ops = len(split_fbo)
     all_ops_dict = {}
     for i in range(1, n_ops):
         strings = fbo.split('<PRESOL>')[i].replace('</PRESOL>', '')
         strings = strings.split('<')
         lists = [x.split('>') for x in strings]
         opp_dict = {}
         desc_count = 0 
         desc = ['OpDesc', 'URL_Desc', 'EMAIL_Desc']
         for ii in lists:
             if len(ii) == 2:
                 if ii[0] == 'DESC':
                     #TODO: Figure out a better name for the duplicate DESC
                     ii[0] = ii[0] + str(desc_count)
                     desc_count += 1

                 opp_dict[ii[0]] = ''.join([x for x in filter(None, ii[1].split('\\n'))])
         all_ops_dict[i] = opp_dict
     return all_ops_dict

f = open('FBOFeed19991231', 'rb')
fbo = str(f.read())
fbop = fbo_parser(fbo)

fbop[68]
RETURNS:>>
{'ADDRESS': 'Christel.Wittmer@ramstein.af.mil',
 'AGENCY': 'Department of the Air Force',
 'CLASSCOD': '32',
 'CONTACT': 'Christel Wittmer, Ms., Phone (49) 631 3539 174, Fax (49) 631 3539 158, Email Christel.Wittmer@ramstein.af.mil - Ursula Nabinger, Ms., Phone (49) 631 3539 178, Fax (49) 631 3539 158, Email Ursula.Nabinger@ramstein.af.mil',
 'DATE': '0720',
 'DESC0': 'WORKBENCH FOR VEHICLE MAINTENANCE,2 METER LONG, TOP IS METAL COVERWERKBANK, 2 METER LANG, SCHICHSTOFF OEL AND FEUCHTIGKEITSBESTAENDIG  (22EA/STCK)WORKBENCH FOR VEHICLE MAINTENANCE, 2 METER LONG TOP CONSISTS 40 MM TICK WOODWERKBANK, 2 METER LANG ARBEITSPLATTE HOLZ MEHRSCHICHTVERLEIMTESBUECHENHOLZ (22EA/STCK)FOR MORE INFO CALL MRS WITTMER 0631-3539-174!',
 'DESC1': 'Link to FedBizOpps document.',
 'DESC2': 'Christel Wittmer',
 'EMAIL': '',
 'LINK': '',
 'LOCATION': '700 CONS',
 'OFFADD': 'United States Air Force, United States Air Force Europe, Rhine Ordnance Barracks, USAFE CONS, UNIT 3115, Germany, .  09094-3115',
 'OFFICE': 'United States Air Force Europe',
 'RESPDATE': '073099',
 'SOLNBR': 'F61521-99T0607',
 'SUBJECT': 'WORKBENCH FOR VEHICLE MAINTENANCE',
 'URL': 'http://www.fbo.gov/spg/USAF/USAFE/ROB/F61521-99T0607/listing.html',
 'YEAR': '99',
 'ZIP': '09021'}
```

Comment: I do not need this any longer but former colleagues probably do, so thank you for sharing with the community!

Comment: Just as an FYI to you, your colleagues or anyone else who needs this... I have since played with it some more and have come to realize this is still not a perfect solution. I am actively working with this data and will try to update this post as I go or at least push to my github @ https://github.com/usmcamp0811/FBO_Parser

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the ftp the following example (I cut out the first fields to focus on the popaddress):

```
In [7]: data = """<PRESOL>
   ...: <DESC>Link To Document
   ...: <SETASIDE>N/A
   ...: <POPCOUNTRY>US
   ...: <POPADDRESS>Moody AFB, GA
   ...: Avon Park, FL
   ...: </PRESOL>"""

In [11]: re.findall(r'<PRESOL>\n<DESC>(.*?)\n<SETASIDE>(.*?)\n<POPCOUNTRY>(.*?)\n<POPADDRESS>(.*?)\n</PRESOL>', data)
Out[11]: []
```

As the last field has a \n not followed by a tag, it doesn't match. That's the problem.

Watching over the data in the FTP I see that there are other multiline fields, like DESC, CONTACT, in some cases quite big and surrounded by HTML tags. Maybe you'd be better off using a more algorithmic method, instead of trying to parse an entire "row" of data with a single regex. I think there might be enough corner cases to consider going at this line by line.

Good luck!

Comment: I think it doesn't really work when he applies it against the data on the ftp link

Comment: I figured with regular expressions you could just say "give me all text in between <SETASIDE> and <POPCOUNTRY>", as I've done before in the past, but for some reason this is giving me lots of problems.

Comment: You can specify multiline matching with the re.M flag. Still, I don't think this problem is suitable for regular expressions (although perhaps you're interested in using/practising with them, in which case it's just fine). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea of creating a data structure that can be turned turned into a table:

```
presol = []
split = re.split('<\/PRESOL>', file_data)

for s in split:
    d = {}
    for k,v in re.findall('<([^>]+)>(.[^<]+)\n', s, re.M|re.S):
        d[k]=v
        presol.append(d)

print("DATE\tAGENCY\tDESC\tURL\tSETASIDE\n")
for p in presol:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(p["DATE"], p["AGENCY"], p["DESC"], p["URL"], p["SETASIDE"]))
```